# Create composite primary key with a name so I can reference it

Tags: mysql, sql

At a workplace they recycle punchcard ids (for some strange reason). So it is common to have past employees clashing with current employees. As a workaround I want to have employee punchcard id, employee name+surname as the unique primary key (fingers crossed,  perhaps add date-of-birth and even passport if available). That can be accomplished with
`PRIMARY KEY (pid,name,surname)`.

The complication is that another table now wants to reference an employee by its above primary key.

Alas, said PK has no name! How can I reference it?

I tried these but no joy:

```
PRIMARY KEY id (pid, name, surname),
```

```
INDEX id (pid, name, surname),
PRIMARY KEY id,
```

```
INDEX id (pid, name, surname) PRIMARY KEY,
```

Can you advise on how to achieve this or even how to reference a composite primary key?

Update:
The table to store employees is `em`.
The table which references an employee is `co` (a comment made by an employee).

Ideally I would use `pid` (punchcard id) as the unique id of each employee. But since `pid`s are recycled, this is not unique. And so I resorted to creating a composite key or an index which will be unique and can reference that as a unique employee id. Below are the 2 tables without the composite key. For brevity,  I abbreviated table names and omitted surname etc. So the question is, how can I reference an employee whose id is composite from another table `co`.

```
CREATE TABLE em (
  pid INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE co (
  id INT primary key auto_increment,
  em INT,
  content VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  constraint co2em_em_fk foreign key (em) references em(pid)
);
```

Comment: ??You can't reference a table by primary key (or any other key) name. You invoke a table in a from or join and join on specified column(s) The data acquisition is handled by sql. Please expand what you mean by this.

Comment: please show a create table i am, unsure what id actually is, the name of the primary key a column? also you can reference a prinary key only to force mysql to use it

Comment: Unclear. Either refer one composite key to another composite key or use generated column which concatenames these columns - depends on your structure and data.

Comment: Personally I would timestamp employees and comments, also it's not clear if 'recycle punchcard ids' means overwrite existing or creating duplicates in employee.

Comment: if an employee with id 1021 leaves and a new one comes, the new one gets the id 1021... But anyway, I wanted a general solution if possible in MySQL where a composite key from  table 1 is referenced as a foreign key in  table 2 without having to create new columns in table 2 equal to the composite key's columns of table1, something suggested by @Sergey Kudriavtsev and also here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=format-defining-composite-primary-foreign-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If another table wants to reference this one by a composite key, you don't need it to have a name - just the list of fields will do. E.g.

```
   CREATE TABLE other_table (
     ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     pid *defintion*,
     name *defintion*,
     surname *defintion*,
     ..., -- other fields, keys etc.
     FOREIGN KEY (pid, name, surname) REFERENCES employees(pid, name, surname)
   );
```

UPD: If you expect that the set of the fields inside PK might change **and** you can't make a simpler PK (auto-increment integer for example) for the original table, then your best bet might be something like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE employee_key (
      ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      pid *defintion*,
      name *defintion*,
      surname *defintion*,
      FOREIGN KEY (pid, name, surname) REFERENCES employees(pid, name, surname)
    );
  
    -- and then reference the employees from other tables by the key from employee_key:
    CREATE TABLE other_table(
      ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      employee_id INT NOT NULL,
      ... -- other fields, indexes, etc...
      FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee_key(ID)
    );
```

Then if you have a change in `employee` table PK, you'll only need to update `employee` itself and `employee_key`, any other tables would stay as is.

If you CAN, however, change the original `employees` table, I would recommend something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  pid *defintion*,
  name *defintion*,
  surname *defintion*,
  ... -- other fields, keys, etc.
  UNIQUE KEY (pid, name, surname)
);
```

Then you'll have to maintain the logic of generating new pid's in your code, though, or have them in some side table.

UPD2: Regarding inserts and updates.

As for inserts: you need to insert these explicitly - otherwise how would you expect the relation to be established? If you're using an ORM library to communicate with your database, then it might provide you with the methods to specify linked objects without explicitly adding the IDs, but otherwise to insert a row into `employees`, `employee_key` and `other_table` you need to first `INSERT INTO employees(...) ;`, then get perform a separate INSERT for the `employee_key` (knowing the key fields you've just added to `employees`), get the auto-generated key from `employee_key` and then use that to perform inserts to any other tables.

You might simplify all this by writing an `AFTER INSERT` trigger for `employees` table (that would automatically create a row in `employee_key`) and/or performing your inserts via a stored procedure (that will even return back the key of the newly inserted row in `employee_key`). But still this work needs to be done, MySQL won't do it for you by default.

Updates are a bit easier, since you can specify `ON UPDATE CASCADE` when adding the foreign key - in that case a change to one of the fields in the `employees` will automatically trigger the same change in any tables that reference `employees` by this key.

Comment: Thank you, I  was afraiid it would come to this... in case of changes in the the schema of the 1st table I must also track changes to all the other tables with foreign-key references to the 1st table :( I was hoping to declare the composition (pid,name,surname) in the 1st column, give it a name and then access that name in any 2nd table which needs to reference it as foreign key. Do I misunderstand correctly, or is this the end of the line for my ambitious canning plan?

Comment: Well, if you change the format for a primary key, you will have to change the format of all the tables that reference it anyway?.. Say, you add the `date_of_birth` as an extra key column - you'll also have to update any tables that reference the original one and add this column there as well. The best you could do is setup an extra "key" table that holds something more stable, such as an auto-increment integer, mapped to a set of key columns from `employees` via FK - then you'll only have to update stuff in _two_ places instead of in every table that references the `employees`.

Comment: perhaps a solution would be to create the composite key programmatically and insert it as a column ```pid_name_surname``` in 1st table.

Comment: ok, thanks Sergey Kudriavtsev

Comment: @bliako Updated my answer with an extra solution

Comment: very clear thank you.

Comment: Quick question: in both your solutions, do the fields ```pid,name,surname``` in either table ```employee_key``` or ```other_table``` need an explicit UPDATE or INSERT? I would think that because they REFERENCE existing cols in ```employees``` then I ONLY have to insert/update them in table ```employees```? That is: insert into ```employees``` and that's it. I do not need to worry inserting the same values in ```other_table``` or ```employee_key```. Right?

Comment: @bliako Unfortunately, mostly no, you'll need to do some hard lifting yourself to make it work. More detailed answer in update in a few minutes.

Comment: @bliako Updated my answer. Note also that if possible, I would _strongly_ suggest adding an auto-generated PK into the `employees` instead. Otherwise you're denormalizing your database, which should only be done for a very good reason since it complicates the code and the maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

You would define it

```
  CONSTRAINT id 
   PRIMARY KEY (pid, name, surname)
```

But you should read more about how MySQL uses INDEXES and how to optimize them

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: This "compiles" ok but I still can't access col/constraint ```id``` from the other table ```co``` with ```constraint xyz foreign key (em) references em(idx)``` (after adding a col ```em VARCHAR(20)```, it complains ```Missing column 'id' for constaint 'xyz' in the referenced table 'em'``` . What I want is really to create a composite key in 1st column and add that as a foreign key on the 2nd column. With above it seems to be getting a name (id) but the 2nd table can't see it!

Comment: you should ahve read the link provided  as you can't access it directly